# Adding Div Classes To PHP Lists

Tags: php, css

Hello I have some php which is generating a list for me. I added the

bits myself and was quite pleased with it actually doing something than giving m a php error

```
    <?php
    $termid = arg(2);
    $terms = taxonomy_get_related($termid, $key = 'tid');
    //print_r($terms);
    foreach($terms as $term){

       $link = url('taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid);
       echo '<li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
     }
  ?>
```

I was wanting to style my list though and tried -

```
    <div class="sidey"><?php
    $termid = arg(2);
    $terms = taxonomy_get_related($termid, $key = 'tid');
    //print_r($terms);
    foreach($terms as $term){

       $link = url('taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid);
       echo '<li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
     }
  ?></div>
```

with-

```
   .sidey .inner ul li, .sidey .view-content div.views-row {
    border-bottom-color: #DDDDDD;
list-style-image: none;
line-height: 130%;
    padding: 5px 0;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

but to no effect. Should this work or am i missing something very fundamental here? I think i am. Also tried this but again to no avail-

```
    <?php
    $termid = arg(2);
    $terms = taxonomy_get_related($termid, $key = 'tid');
    //print_r($terms);
    foreach($terms as $term){

       $link = url('taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid);
       echo '<div id="sidey"><li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li></div>';
     }
  ?>
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: If you assign an ID (<div id="sidey">) then in your CSS you must use #sidey instead of .sidey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the beginning and ending of [unordered list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) `<ul></ul>`

Comment: sorry that was my mistake re the Div ID Alberto. i changed that when i was trying class and ID sorry. The CSS is just not having any effect Zar. Should it all be ok? thanks

Comment: thanks vodich thats done the job. pretty fundemental huh? lol

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to assign an ID to the div then make sure you open and close your UL (like someone mentioned below), then your CSS should be:

```
div#sidey ul li {
    border-bottom-color: #DDDDDD;
    list-style-image: none;
    line-height: 130%;
    padding: 5px 0;
     border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```